# Any suggestions on how to romantically describe a woman's brown hair?

Tags: word-choice

Does anyone know a heartfelt, romantic way to describe the brown hair of a woman/girl? For now, all I have is "silky brown hair," but it just doesn't flow in my poem. This is not official, but I'm doing something along the lines of:

"I look into her diamond eyes and touch her silky brown hair."

I am open to any suggestions. If you think that "silky" is fine, please let me know. If not, please suggest something else. Even if I don't agree with your word choices, anything helps. Perhaps your idea will spark a new one! Compound words and phrases are acceptable. =)

Answer (score 0):

I think silky hair is just too simple as that is one of the most common ways that great hair is described.

You could choose a more specific type of brown, like **chestnut, chocolate or cinnamon brown**. Cinnamon has the benefit that many readers might recall the nice scent.

Or you could emphasise the intensity of the colour: **vibrant auburn hair**.

If the poem is meant for a specific person, of course you cannot deviate from her actual hair colour. But still, finding out the specific tone of brown and using that sounds a bit more interesting to me than just using brown.

Comment: Yes, it's for a specific person. Her hair is more of a chestnut/chocolate brown. I love the word vibrant, so I'll use something like that. Thank you SO much for helping me! The other people over at English Stack Exchange were so rude and didn't want to help me out at all (I think it's because I'm new). Thank you for your help again! You have a blessed day!

Comment: @AsaMatthews [English.se] closed the question as to broad/opinion based.  They weren't being rude, they were just pointing you to a place better suited to your question.  Had you included a picture of some hair, and/or explained a specific problem you had finding a suitable word (e.g. "I need a word to describe hair that changes direction rapidly and puffs up all over the place, but not smoothly enough to be curly" could be answered with "frizzy"), then it might have fit better into their "word-request" category.

Comment: @Chronocidal That makes sense. I had no idea I could give links to photos. I'll remember that. But they were putting me down, which doesn't follow their guidelines.

Comment: @AsaMatthews I have just read through all 10 posts you have made on [English.se], and the responses to them.  I found one comment which was curt and to-the-point, and zero comments "putting you down".

Comment: Hey folks. Please don't discuss these things further here. Sometimes misunderstandings happen, esp. with written communication. Let's leave it at that.